# How can I make it so that when I click a favorite button the selected character's name is added to a dropdown in a list using react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a page that shows several cards with information and a like button that if selected should be saved and displayed in a dropdown list, showing me all the names of the favorites

```
export const CardCharacters = (props) => {
    
    return (
        <div className="card col-sm-4 m-2 bg-secondary p-0" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
            <img src={starWarsPoster} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title mb-4">{props.name}</h5>
                <Link to={"/people/" + props.id}>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary ms-4">Learn More</button>
                </Link>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-warning ms-4">
                    <i className="far fa-heart"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

they should be shown in this other component

```
export const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-dark mb-3 p-0">
            <Link to="/">
                <img src={starWars} className="img-fluid rounded-start p-3 ms-5" style={{ width: "130px", height: "80px" }} />
            </Link>
            <div className="dropdown p-3 me-5">
                <button className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Favorites
                    <span className="badge bg-secondary ms-2">4</span>
                </button>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

Comment: Depending on component structures, you can use useState, central store(redux, recoil, etc,,). The point is that React triggers UI update relying on State change.

Answer (score 0):

So am assuming that this CardCharacters is being rendered from a map and that's why you are passing props in it to get data,

so if you want to update the dropdown list in navbar assuming that these two components don't have a parent child relation what you can do is create a **redux state** ,
(if you don't know about it read about it [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start))

And initialize it as an empty array and update its value whenever you click on the like button, you can add an onClick on your like button where you will first make a copy of your current redux array in a simple array lets call this simple array **temp_array**, you can get the value of your current redux array using useSelector hook which returns that and push the new value (the value you got after clicking on like button) in that temp_array and then replace the current value of redux with the temp_array, we can't do that directly in redux because its immutable. So we first make a copy of current redux array and then push the latest value in that copy and then replace the current value of redux with that copy which contains the changes.

Now in your Navbar component just use useSelector hoook like we did in the onClick function to get the current state of the array (which is now updated) and just map it in your unordered list. Let me know if you are confused about anything